# Adding Tomcat8.5.14 to NetBeans 8.0.2

Tags: tomcat, netbeans-8

I would like some assistance on adding Apache Tomcat8.5.14 to my NetBeans8.0.2 ide. I have tried the normal add server steps but it keeps giving me an error
[image: Error Message on NetBeans]

I am using the most resent release of NetBeans and Tomcat. My installation of Tomcat was successful and It is running correctly[image: Succsfull tOM Cat Installation]

Comment: It seems you are pointing to the **conf** folder of Tomcat itself. Try pointing to its **root** folder instead.

Comment: It later worked only that now when I try running aproject it starts tomcat but does not load the project to it and later throws the error: "UNABLE TO START TOMCAT". Yet when I check the tray i see that TomCat has been started and is running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the correct answer but it got mine working.
After installing Tomcat, restart your computer before trying to add it to netbeans.
You may aslo need to set the path to it in the system configurations for it to be started automatically by netbeans

Comment: @AlvaroJoao, I had the same issue before but after doing that it worked, I bet it may help him